# Adroll Conversion Tracking Enterprise 1.9

Tags: javascript

These are the instructions.  I have put the code in the success file but its not passing any order values back to Adroll.

> Confirm that your AdRoll SmartPixel is placed in the Miscellaneous
>   HTML section in your Magento Admin Panel. In the folder that contains
>   your Magento files, find the file with the path
>   `/app/design/frontend/default/yourskinname/template/checkout/success.phtml`.
>   There are several `success.phtml` files within the root folder, so
>   make sure to find the appropriate one. Open up the file in a text
>   editor and add the following php and javascript code in a place that
>   does not interfere with the code that already lives in the file:
>
> Please click on the link below to show the proper code
>
> ```
> <script type = "text/javascript">
> adroll_conversion_value_in_dollars = <?php echo $total ?>;
> adroll_custom_data = {"ORDER_ID": "<?php echo $this->__($this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId())) ?>"};
> </script>
> ```

https://help.adroll.com/hc/en-us/articles/201974620-Enhanced-Conversion-Tracking-for-Magento

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the JavaScript Code present in the HTML source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's missing some code. `$total` and `$order` aren't defined anywhere.

```
<?php
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
?>
<script type = "text/javascript">
adroll_conversion_value_in_dollars = <?php echo $order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>;
adroll_custom_data = {"ORDER_ID": "<?php echo $order->getIncrementId(); ?>"};
</script>
```